# Reading Data from a Javascript Array returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I'm trying to read the attribubute named "MediaURL" from my Javascript array object. The image below shows an expanded view of my array:

[image]

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'MediaURL' of undefined

Here's my code:

```
    PageMethods.LoadFollowingTab(useremail, onSuccess, onFailure);

      function onSuccess(val) {

          var obj = JSON.parse(val); //this is the array object. I have logged it in console and it's not empty
          obj.forEach(function (value) {
          img1.src = value.Activities[0].MediaURL;
          //I am setting the MediaURL of the first element of the Array as the image source
       });
 }
```

This returns that error. Am I reading the array wrong? What do you think is the problem?

**EDIT**

I pass the result to json using JavaScriptSerializer in the C# Code Behind in ASP.NET:

```
[WebMethod]
 public static string LoadFollowingTab(string email)
 {
       string json = "";

            List<String> following = PBC.LoadFollowingTab(email);

            var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(following);

            return json;
 }
```

Sadly the resulting string is long and I can't post it here. I think the array view I have posted will suffice? :)

Comment: It could be, that you're trying to get MediaURL, before your obj came from async operation, can you post more code? With part of initialization of `obj`. Note that chrome console evaluating object when you expand it in console, not when actualyy printing in console.

Comment: Actually that is not possible since this happens inside onSuccess function. Check my edit please @Andrey

Comment: Can you please post your return JSON information? The contents of obj.

Comment: Do all six array elements have an `Activities` array with at least one element?

Comment: Your forEach is incorrect, is this i direct copy? Its missing a brace and bracket.

`obj.forEach(function (value) {
    img1.src = value.Activities[0].MediaURL;
});`

Comment: @Grimbode As in the json string that comes out as the result?

Comment: @ste2425 it's probably a typo. It wouldn't even run if he had literally forgotten the **)**

Comment: @Earthling yes. Well I'm more interested after you parse it.

Comment: @ste2425 Sorry it's a typo. I'll edit it

Comment: is anything else modifying that object? `console.log` is asynchronous, so you don't see the state during the log call, but when you expand it with a click. Is it the same content if you log it with `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @doldt Yes it's the same content, mate

Comment: @Earthling does **value** always have the same structure?

Comment: @Grimbode Yes it does mate. Same structure everytime. How would you read it? Then we can find the problem

Comment: @Earthling in your success please try this and let me know what you get. **obj[0].Activities[0].MediaURL;**

Comment: @Grimbode What sorcery! It works. Please post it as an answer and explain a bit please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you access `obj` seems correct, however I couldn't help but noticing your comment:

> I am setting the MediaURL of the first element of the Array as the
>   image source

It seems you are only interested on getting the first `MediaURL` of the first value.

```
obj[0].Activities[0].MediaURL;
```

Now what was the problem before? You were looping through your object but you forgot to leave the loop after you got MediaURL.. you just kept on looping and going through every object replacing your img1.src with the next MediaURL (if it ever existed)...

```
obj.every(function (value) {
          img1.src = value.Activities[0].MediaURL;
          //I am setting the MediaURL of the first element of the Array as the image source
          return false;
});
```

It is quite possible that when you kept on looping your `obj` list that one of your `Activities[0] object` was non existant.

When you try to access something that is undefined (or doesn't exist) you get a typeError.

Comment: What if I want to access the MediaURL of the current iteration variable which is 'value' as I have stated in the forEach loop? For example: value.Activities[0].MediaURL? Since the method you specified requires the specific element number to be specified, I would also like to know how to go get the current iteration's MediaURL?

Comment: @Earthling your algo seems correct however I will never be sure unless you give me a portion of your JSON return data that you parse. If I had that information, I would be able to test your code and give you a better answer. If I give you an answer now, I'd only be guessing.

Comment: I see. Can you show me a sample of what you have in mind? I can get an idea and work on it myself then. For example, how you would code it?

Comment: Sorry if i misunderstand your code sample, but returning false in a forEach won't break out. A forEach cannot be prematurely stopped, unless you throw an exception that is.

Comment: @ste2425 you are correct. I was in jQuery mode thing of $.each()

Comment: @Earthling your code is fine, it's just that I don't believe you have the same structure in every array ( value ). http://jsfiddle.net/c8uvbgfu/

Comment: @ste2425 I updated the post. If every() is used then return false will break it.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your time :) Very well explained and it solved my problem! Have a good day